# Compare two values in the same dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary with two key value pairs. I want to compare the values and return true if the items match irrespective of the order of the int[].

This is what I have:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

d1.Add("Inputs", [1,2,3,4])
d1.Add("Outputs", [2,3,1,4])
```

My code is as:

```
if (d1["Inputs"].SequenceEqual(d1["Outputs"]))
        {
            return true
        }
else
        {
            return false
        }
```

I want to return `true` in this case but it returns `false`. Please advise.

Comment: Use. HashSet.SetEquals instead of a List.

Comment: @Dai My dictionary is being set by reading contents from an excel file. I have no hold on the dictionary values. Is there a way to do an item compare?

Comment: You could sort the lists first.

Comment: When you say *"if the items match"* do you mean only if an item appears in both lists, or does the count of each list also need to match?

Comment: Both lists should have same length and same elements.

Comment: Also no need to use `if/else`, just return the result of the check directly.

Comment: Can I use excepts as well?

Comment: `Except` will remove any duplicates, so likely not.

Comment: @RufusL Good points you and TheGeneral made regarding the `Length` which is why I removed my suggestion of using `Any`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` to order each collection, and then use `SequenceEqual` to determine if they have the same number of items, in the same order:

```
var areEqual = d1["Inputs"].OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(d1["Outputs"].OrderBy(i => i));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is answered well by @Rufus.

However, here is an extension method for your *OCD* pleasure. Validates input, returns false on key not found (which you may want as an `KeyNotFoundException`, depending on your fault tolerance level)

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   private static bool CompareValues<T>(
      this IReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<T>> source,  
      string key1, 
      string key2)
   {
      if (source is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key1)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(key1));
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key2)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(key2));

      if (!source.TryGetValue(key1, out var list1)) return false;
      if (!source.TryGetValue(key2, out var list2)) return false;

      return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(
         list1.OrderBy(x => x),
         list2.OrderBy(x => x)
      );
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = d1.CompareValues("Inputs","outputs")
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips earlier regarding my inefficient solution (that would also give false "positives"). Since you pointed out that my solution "would a be quadratic time complexity at worst" would it not be prudent in your solution to also check length before using two `OrderBy` and the `SequenceEqual`?

Comment: hi @Barns SequenceEqual actually does that step "*true if the two source sequences are of equal length and their corresponding elements are equal according to the default equality comparer for their type;*"

Comment: Guess I should have read the docs on `SequenceEqual` before I mentioned it. Thank, again! I learned something new.